# How to close previous activity in android

Tags: android

I have an android application to show  the students details such as name, age , attendence like details...suppose if I use

```
for(int i=0;i<3;i++)
{
Intent student = new Intent(Admin.this,student.class);          
startActivity(student);
}
```

now the student activity creates the activity three new times.What i need is, i want to close 
  previous student activity before the next new activity begins in the for loop. i can not able to use "finish()" because i called it from "Admin" class

Comment: why are you calling  activity in loop?

Comment: I think you follow wrong way :- even though you can use it like:-     Intent student = new Intent(Admin.this,student.class);          
startActivity(student);                                               finish();

Comment: @Giru : Actually i get the student details in three threads in our database servers. i want to update student details for every thread output.

Comment: @sandeep: if i use finish() the admin class closed

Comment: Are you sure this loop will work for i=1,2 ???

Comment: use flags...new task..with student class intent..

Comment: Why You are not using fragment ?

Comment: @meenal: can u give me a sample code for new task..

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> Thank u very much for your replies.... Finally i got solution for this ,, refer my solution below...

```
Intent student = getIntent();
overridePendingTransition(0, 0);
student.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NO_ANIMATION);
finish();

overridePendingTransition(0, 0);
startActivity(student);

Intent student1 = new Intent(Admin.this,student.class);          
startActivity(student1);
```

Comment: gr8 you got solution :)

Answer (score 3):

If you want to close the previous activity, try the following one

```
Intent student = new Intent(Admin.this,student.class);          
startActivity(student);
finish();
```

Answer (score 2):

you can use this

```
  student.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TASK);
  student.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK);
```

or

```
student.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_REORDER_TO_FRONT);
```

for more details on flag read this http://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/Intent.html